# Find the characteristic polynomial of T.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

I am totally a newbie here just want to find the solution for my sister, the below question.

> Let $P_3(\Bbb R)$ be the vector space of all real polynomials of degree less than or equal to three. Let $T$ be a linear operator on $P_3(\Bbb R)$ defined by $T(f(x)) = f'(x) + f''(x)$, where $f'(x)$ is the differentiation of $f(x)$ with respect to $x$. Find the characteristic polynomial of $T$.

Comment: Please show what you've tried.

Comment: You could start by writing the matrix of $T$ in the basis $(1, x, x^2, x^3)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A base of $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ is $B=\left\{1,x,x^2,x^3\right\}$

$T(B)=\left\{0,1,2 x+2,3 x^2+6 x\right\}$

which leads to the matrix

$M_T=
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 6 & 3 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

$\det(M_T-\lambda I)=
\det \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 -\lambda  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & -\lambda  & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 2 & -\lambda  & 0 \\
 0 & 6 & 3 & -\lambda  \\
\end{array}
\right)=\lambda^4$

Characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^4$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Let $f \in P_3(\mathbb{R})$.

Note that since $f$ has degree at most $3$, the $4$-th derivative of $f$ is $0$.

\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&T(f(x)) = f'(x) + f''(x)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&T^2(f(x)) = f''(x) + 2f'''(x)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&T^3(f(x)) = f'''(x)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&T^4(f(x)) = 0\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Since $T^4(f(x)) = 0\;$for all $f \in P_3(\mathbb{R}),\;$it follows that $T^4=0$.

Let $p(t)$ be the minimal polynomial of $T$.

Since $T^4 = 0,\;$it follows that $p(t)$ divides $t^4$.

Since $T^3(x^3) = 6 \ne 0,\;$it follows that $T^3 \ne 0,\;$hence $p(t)$ doesn't divide $t^3$.

Then $p(t)$ must be equal to $t^4$.

Since the dimension of $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ is $4$, it follows that the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is also $t^4$.

Answer (score 0):

The endomorphism is nilpotent, because $T^4(f(x))=0$, for every $f(x)\in P_3(\mathbb{R})$, so the only eigenvalue is $0$ (in whatever extension of the base field). Hence the characteristic polynomial is $\det(T-tI)=(0-t)^n$.